# select layer by area of overlap with another polygon

Tags: arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute

I am working in ArcGIS Pro. I have a polygon (chartreuse) with a fishnet grid laid over it (burnt sienna).
I would like to select those polygons from the burnt sienna fishnet whose areas are greater than 80% contained within the chartreuse polygon.

[image]

I am returning to ArcGIS after many years away. It seems like an SQL query to me, but I don't know how to say "which overlaps 80%"... actually, I don't know how to SQL query in ArcGIS yet, BUT I've been doing lots of coding in R, so I think I could figure it out and probably even the python code if I needed to.

thanks for any guidance!!!!